# What should I do about questions that show no minimal effort/understanding at all?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

I recently saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31427618/3001761) with text in the question explaining that all the code was copied from SO, that they didn't know the language the code was written in or the library that was used and that they desperately needed to know if the code was correct and if not, how to make it work, in order to pass their homework so that they wouldn't fail their internship.

Unlikely to be beneficial to other users? I'm sure someone else will have the same homework question later.

Comment: Downvote / closevote.

Comment: You can down and close vote such questions.

Comment: But what close reason? I'm having trouble finding which one to choose. None seems to fit.

Comment: It sounds like pretty much *every* close reason would fit! If they don't even know whether or not it's correct, then they haven't included *"the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it"*. It's also **too broad** and potentially **unclear what [they're] asking**. Or just use a custom reason (e.g. *"... because we aren't here to do your job for you, you lazy jerk"*). Basically, with stuff like that, I think getting rid of it promptly is more important than dwelling on the most appropriate reason to do so.

Comment: Is it too broad with 10 rows of code and "is this implementation correct"? Or do you mean that it's actually more than one question? It's fairly clear what they are asking.

Comment: Yes, I suppose a better close reason might be **unclear why you thought this would be OK**, but in the absence of that...

Comment: Of course @jonrsharpe is just kidding with *"... because we aren't here to do your job for you, you lazy jerk*" - we'd all put in something less about the user and more about why the post is unsuitable - wouldn't we people? :p

Comment: @JonClements yes... kidding... ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers.

People that don't even have the enthusiasm to lookup what language code might be in or can relate to something that is at least half on a professional level shouldn't be asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow isn't just a Q&A site--it requires a bit more thought and expertise per question and per answer. I've proposed a few proposals about what SO could be and might be to people that are not experts, but most of the community agrees that these types of questions are just out of their scope.

Comment: You don't visit the regex tag often, do you? _"My boss told me I need a regex and I have no intention of learning that, so write it for me"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster to be fair, they said *"shouldn't"* not *"don't"*!